# How can I make some commands only work if you have a specific permission with python?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a command "$clear" which clears a specific number of messages. I do not know how to make this command work if you only have the permission "administrator". If anyone knows how to do this that would help me a lot, and here's my code:

```
async def clear(message, limit:int):
    await message.channel.purge(limit=limit)
    await message.channel.send(f'{limit} messages have been cleared.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)` decorator will only allow administrators to run the given command.

Comment: Thank you, Broken Benchmark! Just to clarify, I would replace @client.command() with @commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)?

Comment: You'd have both decorators.